# Why equivalent capacitor has different value based on the counting side. A simple example is given below!

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor

If I count for the equivalent capacitor value from the beginning then I get 21.6 uF (12 and 6 is in parallel and they are series with 6 6 capacitors.

Now if I reverse the count. 6 and 6 are in series which gives me 3uF and they are parallel with 6 (which gives me 9) and they are in series with 12uF which gives me 5.14 uF.

Whatever path I choose I am getting different values for the equivalent capacitor. What is the right way? WHat I am doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "12 and 6 are in parallel"?

Comment: Label each node and ask the question again and refer to the node you are trying to find the capacitance at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Equivalent capacitor" means that you (virtually) want to replace some part of your circuit by an equivalent single component - a capacitor in your case.

So, you need to first exactly decide which part you want to replace, by e.g. drawing a "cutting line" around the parts to be replaced. If you want to replace with a two-connector component, the cutting line must have exactly two connection points between inside and outside.

It seems to me that you didn't explicitly decide where to draw your cutting line.

Most probably, the problem is meant to calculate the equivalent capacitor when cutting at the battery connection. The inside contains all the capacitors, the outside contains the battery, and the connection points are above and below the battery. Your second path seems to follow this cutting line, while your first is unclear to me (probably even includes the battery).

For the analysis, do incremental replacements step by step:

- Replace the path with C3 and C5 with a combined capacity "C35" for a series connection (this also is a replacement step as described, with C3 and C5 forming the inside, and the two points left of C3 and below C5 being the connection points).
- Replace the parallel capacitors C4 and C35 by a combined capacitor C435 (again a replacement step).
- Replace the series of C1 and C435 by a combined one.

As an exercise (and aid against mistakes), draw the resulting circuit after each step, before you start the next step.

One remark about the battery: if you want to replace a circuit part that contains mixed components, then in the general case you cannot combine them into a single equivalent component. It needs a specific justification to do so:

For a constant-voltage source and a capacitor, their series connection behaves the same as the capacitor alone (based on idealized components, as we generally do).

Answer (score 0):

It is unknown why you think the 12uF is in parallel with any of the 6uF caps so the first approach is wrong, there is nothing in parallel with the 12uF, it is in series with all the other caps.

So the option where 12uF is in series with 9uF is correct.